# Whats wrong with my function not returning this char for my switch

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now. Im suppose to use the function getMenuChoice to prompt the user to make a choice and return the
choice. I just dont know how to use the return in the switch statement. Very confused.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double milesToKilometers();
double kilometersToMiles();
void showMenu();
char getMenuChoice();
int main()
{
    char choice;
    do
    {
        showMenu();
        getMenuChoice();
        switch (toupper(choice))
        {
        case 'A':
            cout << milesToKilometers() << endl;
            break;
        case 'B':
            cout << kilometersToMiles() << endl;
            break;
        case 'Q':
            cout << "Closing" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Not Valid" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }while (choice != 'Q');
    return 0;
}
double milesToKilometers()
{
    cout << "Enter Miles:" << endl;
    double m;
    cin >> m;
    m = m * 1.6093;
    return m;
}

double kilometersToMiles()
{
    cout << "Enter Kilometers: " << endl;
    double k;
    cin >> k;
    k = k * .6214;
    return k;
}
void showMenu()
{
    cout << "A. Miles to Kilometers" << endl;
    cout << "B. Kilometers to Miles" << endl;
    cout << "Q. Quit" << endl;
    return;
}
char getMenuChoice()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "Enter Choice: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: `choice = getMenuChoice();`.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a value that you need to assign to your variable.

```
choice = getMenuChoice();
```

The basic elements are in place, but you missed the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The variable named choice in the switch is not initialized. In you function

```
getMenuChoice();
```

should be

```
choice = getMenuChoice();
```